# How to convert StringCollection to BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, bindinglist, stringcollection, stringdictionary

Is it possible to convert a `StringCollection` variable to a `BindingList`, and then back? I am trying to bind a `StringCollection` to a `DataGridView`, and I am struggling to make it work.

I want to do the same thing with a `StringDictionary`.

Do I need to create some sort of wrapper classes to accomplish this...as described in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568302/use-datagridview-for-local-settings).

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: You should probably add a `C#` tag.

Comment: Just tried to go back and do that (and a WinForms tag) while you were doing it! Thanks. :)

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844412/convert-stringcollection-to-liststring

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you ?

```
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();

        BindingList<String> bl = new BindingList<String>((from String str in sc select str).ToList());
```

Comment: This works for converting the datatype but, when I bind the BindingList to a DataGridView, it does not work correctly. I went back to the article I linked to in my original question and worked through it carefully. I was finally able to work through my errors and get that solution to work. It is an elegant solution, once I figured out how use a custom class as an Application.Settings data type, instead of using the StringCollection. That is the root issue of all of this. Thanks very much for your answer. I will keep syntax you demonstrate, and use it in other areas.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568302/use-datagridview-for-local-settings) solves the issue I was addressing here. Once I carefully worked through the solution given, and corrected my own errors in implementing it, I was able to get it working.

It is an elegant solution.